# error.full_messages are hidden and I can't figure out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm working through a rails tutorial and seem to be stuck on getting some error messages to display on my signup window when an e-mail address, or password is typed in incorrectly. I've included my user controller, new user erb, and error message erb below. Any help would be great. I feel like I've been staring at this forever and getting nowhere.  Thanks in advance for helping.

**Error_Message erb**

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        The form contains <%= @user.errors.count %> errors.
    </div>
    <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li> <%= msg %> </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
@user = User.new
end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
# Handle a succesful save
else
render "new"    
end
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
                                    :password_confirmation)
end
end
```

**New User erb**

```
<%provide(:title, 'Sign up')%>

<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class ="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <% render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

        <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>


    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just change this line:

```
<% render 'shared/error_messages' %>
```

to

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaaah - I don't know if I should feel bad that it took me so long and couldn't find that, or if I should feel motivated and encouraged that you figured it out so quickly. Thanks @Gaurav.